# .msi Installer interrupted

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to run a ".msi" install file.

The installtion fails and I get an "Installer interrupted" error.

I ran the installation with logging and I got the following dump, any ideas?

Dump:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 16/08/2010  9:52:35  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7600.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (80:44) [09:52:35:319]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:52:35:319]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:326]: Resetting cached policy values

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:326]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:326]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:332]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:348]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi' against software restriction policy

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:348]: Note: 1: 2262 2:  DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:348]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi is not digitally signed

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:349]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:354]: Cloaking enabled.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:354]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:357]: End dialog not enabled

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:357]: Original package ==> D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:357]: Package we're running from ==> D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:359]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:359]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{2C6452ED-8958-4F5E-B0FF-18B447D5A9AD}'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:359]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:363]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:364]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:364]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:364]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:364]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:364]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Enabling baseline caching for this transaction since all active patches are MSI 3.0 style MSPs or at least one MSI 3.0 minor update patch is active

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{2C6452ED-8958-4F5E-B0FF-18B447D5A9AD}'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Transforms are not secure.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'D:\Release_1.0.0.0\Log.log'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\pc CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=4480 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{7A1078CC-CD88-4782-B513-597A2B1EE8A1}'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{2C6452ED-8958-4F5E-B0FF-18B447D5A9AD}'

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{2C6452ED-8958-4F5E-B0FF-18B447D5A9AD}'

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install


MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Adding new sources is allowed.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Package name extracted from package path: 'ACC_PIP_UI.msi'

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Package to be registered: 'ACC_PIP_UI.msi'

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:365]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: Running product '{2C6452ED-8958-4F5E-B0FF-18B447D5A9AD}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Users\pc'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '4480'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:366]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:367]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\Favorites

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:367]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:367]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\Documents

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:367]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:367]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:367]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:368]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:368]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:368]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:368]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\Pictures

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:368]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:368]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:369]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:369]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:369]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:369]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:369]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:370]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:370]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:370]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\pc\Desktop

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:370]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:370]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Windows\Fonts

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:371]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'Company User'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'Company'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'D:\Release_1.0.0.0\'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:375]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'D:\Release_1.0.0.0\'.

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:52:35:376]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '5.00'.

=== Logging started: 16/08/2010  9:52:35 ===

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Font 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Doing action: INSTALL

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 

Action 9:52:35: INSTALL. 

Action start 9:52:35: INSTALL.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Running UISequence

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Skipping action: ERRCA_UIANDADVERTISED (condition is false)

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:380]: Doing action: AppSearch

Action 9:52:35: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications

Action start 9:52:35: AppSearch.

AppSearch: Property: IISVERSION, Signature: __FED760E86860437FA0CD3CAE6961E7A4

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:381]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:381]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:381]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding IISVERSION property. Its value is '#7'.

Action ended 9:52:35: AppSearch. Return value 1.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:381]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts

Action 9:52:35: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications

Action start 9:52:35: FindRelatedProducts.

Action ended 9:52:35: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:382]: Doing action: LaunchConditions

Action 9:52:35: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions

Action start 9:52:35: LaunchConditions.

Action ended 9:52:35: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:382]: Doing action: CCPSearch

Action 9:52:35: CCPSearch. Searching for qualifying products

Action start 9:52:35: CCPSearch.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:382]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CCPSearch 3: -2147287038 

Action ended 9:52:35: CCPSearch. Return value 1.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:382]: Doing action: RMCCPSearch

Action 9:52:35: RMCCPSearch. Searching for qualifying products

Action start 9:52:35: RMCCPSearch.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CCPSearch 3: -2147287038 

Action ended 9:52:35: RMCCPSearch. Return value 0.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: Doing action: ValidateProductID

Action 9:52:35: ValidateProductID. 

Action start 9:52:35: ValidateProductID.

Action ended 9:52:35: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: Doing action: WEBCA_TARGETVDIR

Action 9:52:35: WEBCA_TARGETVDIR. 

Action start 9:52:35: WEBCA_TARGETVDIR.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'WEBCA_TARGETVDIR' 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETVDIR property. Its value is 'Gesd.Lim.WebUISetup'.

Action ended 9:52:35: WEBCA_TARGETVDIR. Return value 1.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: Doing action: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE

Action 9:52:35: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. 

Action start 9:52:35: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:383]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE' 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:384]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 2204

MSI (c) (80:98) [09:52:35:384]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI24FD.tmp, Entrypoint: SetTARGETSITE

MSI (c) (80:90) [09:52:35:385]: Cloaking enabled.

MSI (c) (80:90) [09:52:35:385]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server

MSI (c) (80:90) [09:52:35:386]: Connected to service for CA interface.

MSI (c) (80!DC) [09:52:35:425]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 3548

INFO   : [08/16/2010 09:52:35:426] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action is starting...

INFO   : [08/16/2010 09:52:35:426] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...

ERROR  : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:442] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: FAILED: -2146959355

ERROR  : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:442] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action failed with code: '5'

INFO   : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:443] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '5'

MSI (c) (80!DC) [09:53:05:443]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 3548

CustomAction WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

MSI (c) (80:98) [09:53:05:444]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 2204

Action ended 9:53:05: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. Return value 3.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:05:445]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm

Action 9:53:05: FatalErrorForm. 

Action start 9:53:05: FatalErrorForm.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:05:445]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:53:05:447]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:53:05:447]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:53:05:448]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:53:05:449]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:53:05:450]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

Info 2898.For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.

MSI (c) (80:44) [09:53:05:451]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.

Action 9:53:05: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created

MSI (c) (80:E8) [09:53:05:456]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 

Action ended 9:53:09: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.

Action ended 9:53:09: INSTALL. Return value 3.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:608]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.

MSI (c) (80:90) [09:53:09:609]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.

Property(C): UpgradeCode = {9D8EA393-2227-4319-BB67-EC4CDFB50F76}

Property(C): SourceDir = D:\Release_1.0.0.0\

Property(C): TARGETVDIR = Gesd.Lim.WebUISetup

Property(C): IISVERSION = #7

Property(C): ProductName = ACC PIP Website

Property(C): ProductCode = {2C6452ED-8958-4F5E-B0FF-18B447D5A9AD}

Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.0.0

Property(C): Manufacturer = Company Systems Ltd

Property(C): ARPCONTACT = Company Systems Ltd

Property(C): ARPCOMMENTS = ACC PIP Website

Property(C): ARPURLINFOABOUT = http://www.company.com

Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033

Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1

Property(C): TARGETASPNETVERSION = 2.0.50727.0

Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERPRODUCTFOUND

Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2

Property(C): VersionNT = 601

Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?

Property(C): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 4.0 or higher and Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000 or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows Me.  Please install Internet Information Server and run this setup again.

Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.

Property(C): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.

Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.

Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed.

Property(C): AdminMaintenanceForm_Action = Repair

Property(C): VsdAppPoolsCombo = TARGETAPPPOOL

Property(C): VsdSiteCombo = TARGETSITE

Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog

Property(C): SFF_UpFldrBtn = UpFldrBtn

Property(C): SFF_NewFldrBtn = NewFldrBtn

Property(C): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair

Property(C): DefaultUIFont = VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400

Property(C): WelcomeForm_NextArgs = WebFolderForm

Property(C): WebFolderForm_PrevArgs = WelcomeForm

Property(C): WebFolderForm_NextArgs = ConfirmInstallForm

Property(C): ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = WebFolderForm

Property(C): AdminWelcomeForm_NextArgs = AdminWebFolderForm

Property(C): AdminWebFolderForm_PrevArgs = AdminWelcomeForm

Property(C): AdminWebFolderForm_NextArgs = AdminConfirmInstallForm

Property(C): AdminConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = AdminWebFolderForm

Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = D:\Release_1.0.0.0\Log.log

Property(C): PackageCode = {7A1078CC-CD88-4782-B513-597A2B1EE8A1}

Property(C): ProductState = -1

Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1

Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\pc

Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0

Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 4480

Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200

Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00

Property(C): WindowsBuild = 7600

Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 0

Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0

Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1

Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\

Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\

Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\system32\

Property(C): System16Folder = C:\Windows\system\

Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1

Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\

Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\

Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\

Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\

Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\pc\Favorites\

Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\

Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\pc\Documents\

Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\

Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\

Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\

Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\

Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\

Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\

Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\pc\Pictures\

Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\

Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\

Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\

Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\

=Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\

Property(C): GPTSupport = 1

Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1

Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1

Property(C): Intel = 6

Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 3579

Property(C): VirtualMemory = 6000

Property(C): AdminUser = 1

Property(C): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1

Property(C): LogonUser = PC

Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2101819216-1198022024-208953623-25719

Property(C): UserLanguageID = 5129

Property(C): ComputerName = PC

Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 5129

Property(C): ScreenX = 1680

Property(C): ScreenY = 1050

Property(C): CaptionHeight = 22

Property(C): BorderTop = 1

Property(C): BorderSide = 1

Property(C): TextHeight = 16

Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3

Property(C): ColorBits = 32

Property(C): TTCSupport = 1

Property(C): Time = 9:53:09

Property(C): Date = 16/08/2010

Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 2.0.50727.4927

Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7600.16385

Property(C): MsiRunningElevated = 1

Property(C): Privileged = 1

Property(C): USERNAME = Company User

Property(C): COMPANYNAME = Company

Property(C): DATABASE = D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi

Property(C): OriginalDatabase = D:\Release_1.0.0.0\ACC_PIP_UI.msi

Property(C): SOURCEDIR = D:\Release_1.0.0.0\

Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00

Property(C): UILevel = 5

Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL

Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL

=== Logging stopped: 16/08/2010  9:53:09 ===

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:616]: Note: 1: 1708 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:616]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:616]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:616]: Product: ACC PIP Website -- Installation failed.



MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:617]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: ACC PIP Website. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Company Systems Ltd. Installation success or error status: 1603.



MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:618]: Grabbed execution mutex.

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:618]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist

MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:53:09:620]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603

=== Verbose logging stopped: 16/08/2010  9:53:09 ===
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ERROR : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:442] [SetTARGETSITE ]: FAILED: -2146959355

ERROR : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:442] [SetTARGETSITE ]: Custom Action failed with code: '5'

INFO : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:443] [SetTARGETSITE ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '5'

access denied - run the msi with administrative rights

Answer (score 1):

Your WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE Custom Action failed. You might want to add some logging into your custom action functions to log out any exceptions. It looks like it's just bombing out at the minute.

```
...
MSI (c) (80:9C) [09:52:35:384]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 2204
MSI (c) (80:98) [09:52:35:384]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI24FD.tmp, Entrypoint: SetTARGETSITE
...
MSI (c) (80!DC) [09:52:35:425]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 3548
INFO : [08/16/2010 09:52:35:426] [SetTARGETSITE ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO : [08/16/2010 09:52:35:426] [SetTARGETSITE ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
ERROR : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:442] [SetTARGETSITE ]: FAILED: -2146959355
ERROR : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:442] [SetTARGETSITE ]: Custom Action failed with code: '5'
INFO : [08/16/2010 09:53:05:443] [SetTARGETSITE ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '5'
MSI (c) (80!DC) [09:53:05:443]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 3548
CustomAction WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
...
```

Comment: WEBCA_TARGETVDIR is provided by Visual Studio Web Setup Deployment Projects and he won't be able to change it.